# Выделить элементы в нужном порядке

Tags: html, css

Как можно с использованием `nth-of-type` или `nth-child` выделить элементы в таком порядке:

2-3-7-8-12-13-17-18... (начинать со второго, выделять каждые два и пропускать три)

и в таком:

4-5-6-9-10-11-14-15-16...

Пытаюсь сделать разметку для карточек. Первая карточка должна занимать 12 колонок, вторая и третья по 6, четвертая, пятая и шестая по 4, потом опять две карточки по 6, потом три по 4 и так далее...

Примерно так:

`———————————————————————
——————————— ———————————
——————— ——————— ———————
——————————— ———————————
——————— ——————— ———————
——————————— ———————————
——————— ——————— ———————`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример №1

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}

span:nth-of-type(5n + 2),
span:nth-of-type(5n + 3) {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
<span>9</span>
<span>10</span>
<span>11</span>
<span>12</span>
<span>13</span>
<span>14</span>
<span>15</span>
<span>16</span>
<span>17</span>
<span>18</span>
<span>19</span>
<span>20</span>
```

Пример №2

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}

span:nth-of-type(5n + 4),
span:nth-of-type(5n + 5),
span:nth-of-type(5n + 6) {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
<span>9</span>
<span>10</span>
<span>11</span>
<span>12</span>
<span>13</span>
<span>14</span>
<span>15</span>
<span>16</span>
<span>17</span>
<span>18</span>
<span>19</span>
<span>20</span>
```